# How can I force a UINavigationBar to have a smaller height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar

I'd like to have a UINavigationBar with no title that is just 20 pixels in height.

How is this possible?

I tried this and nothing shows up:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20.0);

[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
```

Then I tried this and the height is fixed to whatever Apple is using:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20.0);

[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

UINavigationItem* navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];

[navigationBar setItems:@[navigationItem]];
```

Comment: the moment for a subclass has come. In there you can change the `intrinsicSize` method which should change it, because you can not set the intrinsicSize from outside and UINavigationBar is a general Navigation Element that has to have a certain size to make use of it. It should have a size even if you do not set the frame. But you can set a private member variable in your implementation of initWithFrame that will return the proper size when intrinsicSize is asked for its size.

Comment: If you write an answer with a code snippet I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80.0) // set height whatever you required
```